# Angular unit test mockbackend SPEC HAS NO EXPECTATIONS

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am using Jasmine & Karma for unit testing angular app . I have wrote unit test like this

```
it('should match request object', inject([UserService, MockBackend], (userService: UserService, mockBackend) => {
    mockBackend.connections.subscribe((connection: MockConnection) => {
        expect(connection.request.method).toEqual(RequestMethod.Post);
        expect(connection.request.json().getUserProfileRequest).toEqual({
            userid: '1234',
        });

        connection.mockRespond(new Response(new ResponseOptions({
            body: UsersMockData.GET_USER_PROFILE,
        })));
    });

    usersService.getUserProfile(1234)
        .subscribe(data => {
            expect(data).toBe(UsersMockData.GET_USER_PROFILE);
        });
}));
```

Everything works fine and no issue now when I split test cases in to two separate test cases I write code like this

```
it('Check userProfile request', inject([UserService, MockBackend], (userService: UserService, mockBackend) => {
    mockBackend.connections.subscribe((connection: MockConnection) => {
        expect(connection.request.method).toEqual(RequestMethod.Post);
        expect(connection.request.json()getUserProfileRequest).toEqual({
            userid: '1234',
        });
    });
}));

it('check return data from service', inject([UserService, MockBackend], (userService: UserService, mockBackend) => {

 connection.mockRespond(new Response(new ResponseOptions({
                body: UsersMockData.GET_USER_PROFILE,
            })));

  usersService.getUserProfile(1234)
    .subscribe(data => {
        expect(data).toBe(UsersMockData.GET_USER_PROFILE);
    });
}));
```

Both of these test cases are having expect statement but when I execute test cases , I see a message **SPEC HAS NO EXPECTATIONS** for both test cases . I am wondering why it shows spec has no expectations.

Comment: Because if you don't subscribe to getUserProfile the backend never gets called, and if you don't provide the mock response from the backend there's no event for your subscription.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I missed a piece of code which will get mock data , updated code . Can you please be more thorough what are your trying to say ?

Comment: Your second test would fail because what even is a connection outside the mock backend subscription? Why are you trying to split this up?

Comment: @jonrsharpe split up to make it more readable , rather than testing all logic in single use case

Answer (score 3):

If you don't `.subscribe` to you method, the get request will never be made so the mock backend is never invoked. If you don't provide a mock response, the subscription to your method will never receive a value. Therefore, to reach the expectations at all, you must have a certain amount of minimal wiring in each test. In your case:

```
it('Check userProfile request', inject([UserService, MockBackend], (userService: UserService, mockBackend) => {
    mockBackend.connections.subscribe((connection: MockConnection) => {
        expect(connection.request.method).toEqual(RequestMethod.Post);
        expect(connection.request.json().getUserProfileRequest).toEqual({
            userid: '1234',
        });
    });

    usersService.getUserProfile(1234).subscribe(data => {});
}));

it('check return data from service', inject([UserService, MockBackend], (userService: UserService, mockBackend) => {
    mockBackend.connections.subscribe((connection: MockConnection) => {
        connection.mockRespond(new Response(new ResponseOptions({
            body: UsersMockData.GET_USER_PROFILE,
        })));
    });

    usersService.getUserProfile(1234)
        .subscribe(data => {
            expect(data).toBe(UsersMockData.GET_USER_PROFILE);
        });
}));
```